# UITabBarController without NavigationController?

Tags: objective-c

I wonder if it is possible to create a UITabBarController without declaring, one uiNavigationController?

because in some examples that I find on the internet, all make use of navigationcontroller and then report a tab bar, as I am a beginner, I would like you answer me the question above

Answer (score 0):

Yes; any viewcontroller can be embedded within a tabBarController.  Ray Wenderlich has a good tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nav controller for use tab controller. Just create a tab bar controller, setup him, and insert controllers you want.